# Comment or uncomment Laravel Localizations config file

Tags: laravel, configuration-files, laravel-localization

I'm using `mcamara/laravel-localization`. Admin can add or delete the specific supported languages in dashboard, so I need to comment or uncomment some lines in  `Laravel Localizations` config file from my controller.
Config file screenshot down below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g5q1.png

Comment: show me the code

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g5q1.png